# Show that the group $G=\langle a, b\mid a^3, b^3, c=b^{-1}a^{-1}ba, ac=ca, bc=cb\rangle$ has order $27$.

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

This is Exercise 1.2.21 of Magnus *et al*'s book on combinatorial group theory.

### The Question:

> Show that the group $$G=\langle a, b\mid a^3, b^3, c=b^{-1}a^{-1}ba, ac=ca, bc=cb\rangle$$ has order $27$.

### Thoughts:

We can rewrite the presentation for $G$ as $$\langle a, b\mid a^3, b^3, [a, [b, a]], [b, [b, a]]\rangle,$$ where $[x, y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, by letting $c=[b, a]$, multiplying $ac=ca$ on the left by $a^{-1}c^{-1}$, and multiplying $bc=cb$ on the left by $b^{-1}c^{-1}$. In words, $a$ and $b$ commute with the commutator $[b, a]$.

We have, then, that
$$\begin{align}
e&=a^{-1}[b, a]^{-1}a[b, a] \\
&=a^{-1}[a, b]a[b, a] \\
&=\dots
\end{align}$$ but I don't know where I'm going with that.

I'm reminded of Lie algebras. It's been too long since I've studied them however.

### Context:

I'm studying for a PhD in combinatorial group theory, first year.

I'm familiar with similar questions: there's a general technique of, say, showing that one can write the elements of a group as a word of some form (in the generators, of course), then performing combinatorial arguments on the powers of the generators. I can't seem to do it here.

What kind of answer am I looking for? Well, a rigorous argument for why the group has order $27$ would be great. Combinatorial group theoretic approaches are strongly preferred.

I reckon I should be able to solve this problem myself, given enough time. I'm still practicing the basics . . .

Please help :)

Comment: It's got to be something simple, right? I've got the feeling it is.

Comment: Well, $c$ is central in the group, since it commutes with all generators, and $abc=ba$ so you can commute $a$ and $b$ past each other by creating exhaust of a bunch of $c$s, so you can write any element in the form $a^ib^jc^k$ where $i,j\in \{0,1,2\}$, since $a^3=b^3=1$.  So you just need to show $c$ has order $3$.  But $c^3=1$ is usually included as one of the relations when defining the non-abelian group of order $27$ and exponent $3$ by generators and relations.  I'm not sure how to get $c^3=1$ from the relations in the exercise.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know how to do that.  It's usually included as one of the relations.

Comment: Do you think it might be omitted by mistake? I've copied the question verbatim.

Comment: I can't think of a good reason to think it's a mistake, and it would be a pretty easy exercise with that relation added.  I'd suggest taking a look at the material shortly before that exercise appears to see if something might help.

Comment: Or in this case just look at the exercise just before it, which pretty much steps you through a proof.

Comment: @CMonsour Hahaha! Well, isn't that embarrassing!? I didn't notice it. It's late here in the UK and I thought I'd tackle it for fun. The proof goes along the lines of what I said in the **Context** section above then. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, well, not quite what I said. Close enough . . .

Comment: @CMonsour It isn't enough just to prove that $c^3=1$; you also need to prove that $c\neq1$. Also, as an alternative to your commutator re-writing, you can just note that $\langle c\rangle$ is normal and that $G/\langle c\rangle$ has order $9$.

Comment: (For example, you can spot that $G$ is a semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3=\langle b, c\rangle$ with $\mathbb{Z}_3=\langle a\rangle$, with action $a^{-1}ba=bc$, $aba^{-1}=bc^{-1}$, and of course $aca^{-1}=c$.)

Comment: Sure, but that part is trivial, since the existence of a group of order 27 satisfying these relations is well known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly more generally, the last two relations essentially tell you that the group has nilpotency class at most $2$. Nilpotent groups always allow you to collect elements in a nice way, a little bit like  C Monsour  said in the comments. You first collect generators to the left (say) at the cost of creating some commutators. You then collect first-level commutators, at the cost of creating higher commutators. And so on, at some point, the process stops, because of nilpotency.

It also turns out that, restrictions on the order of elements give restrictions on the order of their commutators.
For example, if $c=[a,b]$ as here, then $a^b=ac$. Now, for every integer $n$, we have $(a^n)^b=(a^b)^n=(ac)^n$. If $a$ and $c$ commute, then we get  $(a^n)^b=(ac)^n=a^nc^n$. So, if $a^n=1$, then also $c^n=1$.

(This is very similar to the argument by Nelyudov (user584025), but I think a bit more enlightening. The argument is also more general:  if we have $c=[a,b]$, then  $[a,c]=1$ and $a^n=1$ already imply $c^n=1$. So we don't need to use $b^n=1$ or $[b,c]=1$ for this conclusion.)

Comment: A small comment: all of this only shows that the group under question has order at most $27$. To finish the problem, you can for example exhibit a group of order $27$ satisfying the relations.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
c&=b^{-1}a^{-1}ba\\
&=b^2a^2ba\\
&=b^2a^2b(c^{-1}c)a\\
&=c^{-1}b^2a^2bca\\
&=c^{-1}b^2a(abc)a\\
&=c^{-1}b^2aba^2\\
&=c^{-2}b^2(abc)a^2\\
&=c^{-2}b^3a^3\\
&=c^{-2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I adore how elegant this is.

Answer (score 1):

This is the presentation for [$U(3,3)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Unitriangular_matrix), the Heisenberg group over $\Bbb{Z}/3$ of order $3^3=27$.
If we take $a,b\in G$ such that $aZ(G),bZ(G)$ generate $G/Z(G)$, then $1\not= [a,b]$ generates $Z(G)$, so $a,b$ generate $G$.  If $a,b$ both have order $3$, we obtain our presentation $\langle a,b\mid a^3,b^3,[a,b]=[a,b]^a=[a,b]^b\rangle$.

Reference: K. Conrad's article [Groups of order $p^3$](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf).